# Characteristic polynomial of a matrix — algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

Is there a classical algorithm to compute the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of a real matrix, for small matrix sizes (say up to $10\times10$)?

Is there a specialized version for symmetric matrices?

Note that I am not after the roots of this polynomial (i.e., the eigenvalues).

Comment: You mean aside from the obvious $\det(A - \lambda I)$? What properties do you require from the algorithm?

Comment: Some references: [Faddeev–LeVerrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm), [Samuelson–Berkowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuelson%E2%80%93Berkowitz_algorithm), [CHACM](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2824498_The_CHACM_Method_for_Computing_the_Characteristic_Polynomial_of_a_Polynomial_Matrix).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: yes, $\det(A-\lambda I)$, but in algorithmic form. I expect it to be efficient, but not too hard to code from scratch.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: the CHACM paper claims complexity $O(n^5)$ for Faddeev-Leverrier (other sources $O(n^4)$). This is large !

Comment: Off the top of my head, any algorithm for computing the [Hermite normal form](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~astorjoh/issac11hermite.pdf) (as defined in the linked paper) should be useful for your purpose. That might give you something to google.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If your matrix is only $10 \times 10$, is $O(n^5)$ really so bad?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I would prefer $O(n^3)$ :-)

Comment: @Yves You might also consider bootstrapping any algorithms for computing the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)

Comment: Can't you do plain old Gaussian elimination/Bareiss?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: that could be an option, using polynomial arithmetic. I was hoping for a straight algorithm, and indeed Faddeev-Leverrier is one such solution. I also saw a mention of building the Lagrangian interpolation polynomial (from computed determinants).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Bocher's formula is exactlywhat you need. Let A be an nxn matrix and $ \beta_i $ the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-i} $ in $ det(\lambda I -A) $. Let $ t_i =tr(A^i) $.Then
 $$ \beta_1=-t_1 $$  $$ \beta_2=-(1/2)(\beta_1t_1+t_2) $$
$$ \beta_i=-(1/i)(\beta_{i-1}t_1+ ... +\beta_1t_{i-1}+t_i) $$ for $ i\le n $ This formula is valid with the entries in A in any commutative ring with identity in which the elements 2,3, ... ,n are all invertible.

Comment: This is Leverrier. The powers of the matrix each require $\Theta(n^3)$ operations, and you need to compute $n$ of them. Is there a more efficient procedure ?